Repeatable reads transaction level
-- TRANSACTION 1
set transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION
select name from student where id=1
waitfor delay '00:00:15'
update Student set name='abc' where id=1
commit transaction
-- TRANSATION 2
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
update Student set name='xyz' where id=1
commit transaction
I run the transaction1 later transaction2 so first it will be locked for transaction1 and transaction2 should fail but its happening reverse
Transaction2 is successfull and transation1 is failed
